# Can you access multiple photos with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, pyinstaller

Is it possible for pyinstaller to include multiple photos (.gif files). I use loads of photos in a Tkinter GUI, but I'm unsure whether or not this will work. My images are in different folders than the .py file, but I use the whole path when using the photos in my application.

I also use several .txt files in my program (kept in the same folder as the .py file), and a .wav file. Will my program still be able to access these?

Basically, is it possible to have an executable file that can access sound, image, and text files using pyinstaller.

I need to be able to distribute this as well. So, I need my exe to be able to access those photos, text files, and sound files when on another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience, I guess you can move all the needed files into the folder where the executable is located (i.e. `dist/`) after building your application.

---

You can also do this in a single command: `pyinstaller main.py --add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>` for adding additional non-binary files to the executable.

> The path separator is platform specific, `os.pathsep` (which is `;` on Windows and `:` on most unix systems) is used. This option can be used multiple times.

---

Alternatively, you can change the spec file generated by PyInstaller to add additional data files to your app.

1. Create a spec file using `pyi-makespec main.py`.
2. Change the spec file to include your data files:

```py
a = Analysis(..., datas=[('path/to/your/file', '.'),], ...)
```

> - The first string specifies the file or files as they are in this system now.
> - The second specifies the name of the folder to contain the files at run-time.

3. After you have created a spec file and modified it as necessary, you build the application by passing the spec file to the pyinstaller command: `pyinstaller main.spec`.

Reference: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html

Comment: Would this still work if I distributed my exe to to other people? For example, if I put this online to download, would I need to change any code or anything. Currently my code just references the path to each file locally, would I have to change this to os.getpath() (I don't know the actual function) or whatever to account for the fact that the user might not have that exact path to each file on their computer?

Comment: @jack.py I don't think so. I have tested it myself. You need to distribute the whole directory containing both the executable and the additional files. If you want to distribute your app more easily, you can specify the `--onedir` option to make all the things into a single directory.

Comment: @jack.py Since you should have specified "the name of the folder to contain the files at run-time" in the spec file, you won't need to worry about that the user might not have that exact path to each file on their computer, unless they manually move away the files from the original location you have specified in the spec file.